# Softlayer Object Storage Auth Endpoint

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've been reviewing documentation for the Softlayer object storage auth endpoint found here: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Introduction-Object-Storage#Authentication_Endpoints

However I can't find any examples of how to exactly pass the authentication information over - do I send it via headers? If so what are the header names?

I've tried using the following endpoint: Public Network: https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0

And also using headers such as x-auth-token for the password and x-auth-user for the username.

I also tried authentication using Http Basic authentication.

No luck on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look the following link:

[Managing SoftLayer Object Storage Through REST APIs](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis) - "Authenticating to the Object Storage" section.

According to the link, you can get "X-Auth-User" and "X-Auth-Key" values in

> Control Portal. Storage >> Object Storage >> Select Object Storage >>
>   Select Cluster (e.g. Dallas 5) >> View Credentials,

where

> "X-Auth-User" refers to "Username"
>   "X-Auth-Key" refers to "API Key
>   (Password)".

Here an example using curl:

```
curl -i -H "X-Auth-User: SLOS300001-10:rcuellar" -H "X-Auth-Key: 231222489e90646678364kjsdfhytwterd02599813f463619d5728e0293de8" https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0
```