# Object Storage Access Controls API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I have looked all through the SoftLayer API documentation, but I cannot find any reference to how one manages which portal users may access the Object Storage authentication endpoints to get the access token.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998943/softlayer-object-storage-auth-endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wish an user have access to the object storage you have to grant the following permissions:

"Manage CDN Account", "Manage CDN File Transfer" and "Manage Storage"

Remove the permissions above in order to not let your user to access the object storage

see:

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/can-user-have-cdn-and-storagelayer-permissions-granted-be-prohibited-accessing-object-storage
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/can-sub-user-access-object-storage
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/manage-object-storage-user

using API you can set the permissions using these methods:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addBulkPortalPermission
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/removeBulkPortalPermission

here an example:
https://gist.github.com/underscorephil/7583408

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be similar to this question:

[Softlayer Object Storage Auth Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998943/softlayer-object-storage-auth-endpoint)

References:

[Managing SoftLayer Object Storage Through REST APIs](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis)