# What is the API service and method to give a user access to an Object Storage account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm looking for the API equivalent of the "Manage Users" operation that appears in the SoftLayer Portal when displaying an Object Storage account.

I have a situation where I'm creating both a new softlayer userid and object storage account in python code and need to be able to give that user access to the object storage account to create containers and upload files.

I'd be expecting something like `client.call('Network_Storage','addUser',new_username,id=storage_id])`

but I can't find anything in the SLDN api reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to grant some permissions to the users, see this post for more information

[Object Storage Access Controls API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783992/object-storage-access-controls-api)

Regards