# DB2 Warehouse on Cloud Load_jobs filename or path is not valid failure

Tags: object-storage, dashdb, db2-woc, ibm-cloud-platform

I have to try to load data to DB2 WoC (formerly dashDB) from IBM Cloud Object Storage (Softlayer) by using `/load_jobs` API call.

Always getting error response: `SQL3025N,A parameter specifying a filename or path is not valid.,0,n/a`

Trying different formatting for `path` key, like following:

`us-south/woctestdata/data_example.csv
/woctestdata/data_example.csv
woctestdata/data_example.csv
woctestdata::data_example.csv`

*also tried folowing suggestions from comments:*

`us-south::woctestdata\data_example.csv
us-south::woctestdata::data_example.csv`

So no more ideas. How the path should be entered correctly?

There is the example of my request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://dashdb-mpp.services.dal.bluemix.net/dashdb-api/v2/load_jobs \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <api_key>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "load_source": "SOFTLAYER",
    "load_action": "INSERT",
    "schema": "MKT_ATBTN",
    "table": "TRANSMISSIN_TABLE1",
    "max_row_count": 0,
    "max_warning_count": 0,
    "cloud_source": {
      "endpoint": "https://tor01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0",
      "path": "woctestdata/data_example.csv",
      "auth_id": "<auth_id>",
      "auth_secret": "<auth_secret>"
    },
    "server_source": {
      "file_path": "string"
    },
    "stream_source": {
      "file_name": "string"
    },
    "file_options": {
      "code_page": "1208",
      "column_delimiter": ";",
      "string_delimiter": "",
      "date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "time_format": "HH:MM:SS",
      "timestamp_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",
      "cde_analyze_frequency": 0
    }
  }'
```

I also try to use db2 load command to load data from IBM Cloud object storage. But also no luck:

```
db2 load from Softlayer::https://tor01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0::IBM:<ibm_email_address>::<password>::woctestdata::data_example.csv of del insert into MKT_ATBTN.TRANSMISSIN_TABLE1;
```

Result:

```
      Agent Type     Node     SQL Code     Result
_______________________________________________________________________
  PRE_PARTITION  000      -00003025    Error.
_______________________________________________________________________
  RESULTS:       0 of 0 LOADs completed successfully.
_______________________________________________________________________

Summary of LOAD Agents:
Number of rows read         = 0
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows loaded       = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows deleted      = 0
Number of rows committed    = 0

SQL3025N  A parameter specifying a filename or path is not valid.
```

Comment: Does `us-south::woctestdata/data_example.csv` work for you?

Comment: @P. Vernon No, it is not wotk either. Tried following variants: us-south::woctestdata\data_example.csv, us-south::woctestdata::data_example.csv

Comment: Do you get the same problem with the v3 API?

Comment: @P. Vernon Where I can see v3 API documentation? The DB2 WoC provide only rest API v2 for now.

Comment: At the top of the V2 doc https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/85/api/db2whc/ there is a link to the latest version here https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/85/api/db2whc-v3/

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, you might need to open a support case

Answer (score 0):

To download or access to the file you need to get an **X-Auth-Token** or set its container with an static URL through the Web page.

### **X-Auth-Token**

I recommend to review [Managing the Object Storage](https://softlayer.github.io/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis/) and [softlayer-object-storage-auth-endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998943/softlayer-object-storage-auth-endpoint)

When you run the command

```
curl -i -H "X-Auth-User: SLOS300001-10:rcuellar" -H "X-Auth-Key: 231222489e90646678364kjsdfhytwterd0259" https://tor01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0
```

The response is something like this:

```
X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkb26239d441d6401d9482b004d45f7259 – the token we need
X-Storage-Url: https://tor01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6
```

And now you should be able to access to the file with an URL similar like below:

```
https://tor01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6/woctestdata/data_example.csv
```

### **Static URL through Web Page**

In the portal page go to:

> Storage >> Object Storage >> Select Object Storage >> Select Cluster
>   (e.g. Toronto) >> Select your container

And check the **Enable Static Site** checkbox, see image below.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that we using Softlayer in IBM Cloud. IBM Cloud Object Storage build on SoftLayer technology but the interface is very different. It is one of the bluemix services and I just do not see options that you describe.

Answer (score -1):

you also can use endpoints + object path, the path format is bucketname::filename

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).